# How to load an FBX animation file in ASSIMP?

Tags: opengl, assimp

I have an example from a LearnOpenGL tutorial which loads the animations. Now, I want to use that to render FBX animation, but the result is totally wrong.

What I want is simply to load an FBX animation with the human skeleton from Mixamo.

Are there any examples of it?

Answer (score 2):

We have a simple example in the assimp-repo. You can find it here: [Simple Snake as a FBX-File](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/tree/master/test/models/FBX)

It is just a snake with a simple skeleton with the following form:

```
parentbone -> childbone -> childbone -> ...
```

You can use it to test you bone-implementation.

The examples used in the most tutorials are containing animations for characters. The snake contains just one tree with some vertices modified by the vertex-weights stored in the aiMeshes.

When this example works try your human.

Comment: Hello, Kim, thanks for your answer. would like give me a git pointer to this?

Comment: Hi, I have added some more information. Hope that helps!

Comment: Has the snake been removed from assimp?